# what is the equivalent of a MongoDB collection in Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

... and if there is no equivalent, how should I go about to organize my data in a Morphia datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `@Entity` classes, which define your collections, and the instances are your documents.

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thx! Indeed I had found it after posting my question. But I had a follow up: is it possible to name these entities dynamically? (as in: @Entity ("userInput.uniqueId"))

Comment: If I'm not mistaken: Annotations in Java contain static, class-level information. You might be able to hack something together with reflection / Javassist, but that's not in core and I'd carefully consider if this is really a good approach...

Answer (score 2):

You can change the name of the collection using AdvancedDatastore interface. For example:

```
advancedDatastore.save("collectionNameYouPrefer", yourMorphiaObject);
```

Above code will save yourMorphiaObject into the collection named "collectionNameYouPrefer".